# Enlarging pictures programmatically in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, android-image

I am able to retrieve the pictures from my phone and store them in an array. After that I am displaying them on the screen. But they are all in diffrent shapes and sizes. I want to display them all in the same size and shape. Any idea?

```
photoPaths = new ArrayList<String>();   
     getAllPhotos(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), photoPaths);
     images = new Bitmap[photoPaths.size()];


         apa = (AnimationPhotoView)findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
        for(int i=0;i<photoPaths.size();i++)
        {
            File imgFile = new  File(photoPaths.get(0));

            if(imgFile.exists())
            {

                images[0] = decodeFile(imgFile);}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tedd);

    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();

    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();


    int newWidth = 200;

    int newHeight  = 200;

    // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f

     float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;

     float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

     Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

     matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
     matrix.postRotate(x);
     // this will create image with new size
     Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0,width, height, matrix, true);

     iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
     iv.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!! I need to wait in order to accept. Thanks Mac

Comment: Actually I get an exception when using this: `IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits`, check my answer instead.

Comment: use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16248911/1289716) so you will not get `Bitmap size exceeds`

Answer (score 1):

I am using:

```
Bitmap bitmap = //Your source

int newWidth = //compute new width
int newHeight = //compute new height

bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, scaleWidth, scaleHeight, true);
```

The last `boolean` is `filter`, which makes your image smoother.

The solution presented by MAC above gave me an `IllegalArgumentException: bitmap size exceeds 32bits`.

This only scales the bitmap though and doesn't rotate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display jpg-images or image formats which are "known" by android, you can simply use the MediaStore.Images and retrieve the Thumbnails, this is faster and needs less memory and the images should already all the same format (Width+Height).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.html

Answer (score 0):

i think you can try this also.

```
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f)
{
    try 
    {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=200;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true)
        {
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }
        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```